# Как в функцию PostgreSQL передать массив пользовательских типов

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

У меня есть пользовательский тип массива в Postgres:

```
CREATE TYPE core.arr_message_input AS (
    idmessage uuid,
    idplugin integer,
    versionplugin numeric,
    ttl integer
);
```

Есть простая функция для добавления записей в таблицу:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION queue_push(
    arr_message_input[])
    RETURNS Bool
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO queue(idmessage, idplugin, versionplugin, queuetime, ttl)
        SELECT idmessage, idplugin, versionplugin, now(), ttl
        FROM unnest ($1);
        RETURN True;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN others THEN
            RETURN False;
    END $$;
```

Заполнить значениями из Postgres легко:

```
SELECT queue_push(
    array[
        ('e62c7924-2cd1-4dd6-9b55-d4e612816ce0', 2, 0, 0),
        ('a7e864af-4c4c-452d-9df2-f9d4f70ac02e', 2, 0, 0),
    ]::arr_message_input[]
);
```

Но через SQLAlchemy не могу понять, как это сделать. Передаю ей list, как array, но здесь должен быть список списков или что-то похожее. И у меня никак не получается выполнить это из питона.

Например:

1. Модель функции описана следующим образом:

```
class QueuePush(GenericFunction):

    name = "queue_push"

    @staticmethod
    def mapped_objects(**kwargs):
        return select(
            [
                Column('queue_push', BOOLEAN),
            ]
        ).select_from(
            func.queue_push(
                kwargs['arr_message_input'],
            )
        ).alias(name="queue_push")
```

Запрос к функции:

```
import QueuePush


messages = [
    ['027d6e96-84b7-4f10-8640-13dfa1b05fd8', 3, 0, 2],
]

queue = db.query(QueuePush.mapped_objects(arr_message_input=messages)).all()
```

Но все же, созданный тип это некая структура данных. Я явно что-то делаю не так.

Comment: Приведите пример кода, где "не получается".

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, добавил

Comment: Если нашли решение - добавьте ответом. Добавлять "решено" в загловок здесь не принято.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил перевести ответ [Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4) с англоязычного StackOverflow (может кому-то будет полезнее).
Как позднее написали в комментарии так будет правильнее.

В SQLAlchemy синтаксис кортежа может быть создан с помощью `tuple_()`, а с помощью `postgresql.array()` можно создавать литералы массива. Объединяя их, вы получаете:

```
from sqlalchemy import tuple_
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array

class QueuePush(GenericFunction):

    name = "queue_push"

    @staticmethod
    def mapped_objects(**kwargs):
        input = array([tuple_(*t) for t in kwargs['arr_message_input']]
        return select(
            [
                Column('queue_push', BOOLEAN),
            ]
        ).select_from(
            func.queue_push(

                input.op("::")(text("arr_message_input[]"))
            )
        ).alias(name="queue_push")
```

Для расширенного использования вы можете определить UserDefinedType и bind_expression():

```
from sqlalchemy import tuple_
from sqlalchemy.types import UserDefinedType

class ArrMessageInput(UserDefinedType):

    def get_col_spec(self, **kw):
        return "arr_message_input"

    def bind_expression(self, val):
        return tuple_(*val)
```

и затем

```
from sqlalchemy import tuple_
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array, ARRAY

class QueuePush(GenericFunction):

    name = "queue_push"

    @staticmethod
    def mapped_objects(**kwargs):
        # По какой-то причине `bind_expression` не применяется к элементам массива,
        # даже если используется `array(..., type_=ArrMessageInput)`
        input = array([tuple_(*t) for t in kwargs['arr_message_input']])
        return select(
            [
                Column('queue_push', BOOLEAN),
            ]
        ).select_from(
            func.queue_push( 
                input.cast(ARRAY(ArrMessageInput))
            )
        ).alias(name="queue_push")
```

С другой стороны, если вы используете psycopg2, вы можете положиться на его адаптацию списков и кортежей Python и просто передать структуру в виде литерала, приведенного к правильному типу:

```
from sqlalchemy import literal
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

class QueuePush(GenericFunction):

    name = "queue_push"

    @staticmethod
    def mapped_objects(**kwargs):
        input = literal([tuple(t) for t in kwargs['arr_message_input']])
        return select(
            [
                Column('queue_push', BOOLEAN),
            ]
        ).select_from(
            func.queue_push( 
                input.cast(ARRAY(ArrMessageInput))
            )
        ).alias(name="queue_push")
```